# CSS Framework in ASP/ASP.NET for relatively complex forms - criteria for choosing?

Tags: asp.net, css

I'm thinking about using one of the existing grid or other CSS frameworks for an ASP site and an ASP.NET site, but want to make sure I get something that can do relatively complex forms and work in Fox (compatibility would be nice, but not essential)

What criteria did you use to pick out your chosen CSS development layout tools? What products met that critera?

Answer (score 1):

CSS frameworks and regular ASPX pages, it's not so bad. You have to do a bit of custom stuff for the added HTML/way things are handled in ASP.net but it's no show stopper. I personally perfer to just use a solid Reset/Baseline (like Yahoo! - [Reset](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/cssreset/), [Base](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/cssbase/), [Grids](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/cssgrids/)). I've always liked Yahoo! the best because it's been the most reliable across browsers - but that's just me. The reset and baseline will get rid of a lot of their weird quirks across browsers. jQuery would be an added tool you should have to help keep it consistent with more dynamic/programmatic things.

If you're going the MVC route, you can pretty much use whatever you'd like because you don't need to worry about the custom HTML that ASP.NET typically adds. [Blueprint](http://www.blueprintcss.org/) is another popular one out there. I've used it on a couple of projects and it's good.

As for CSS grids and complicated forms. One of the biggest issues that I've always run into is you have a handful of form elements that you're not going to want to conform to the strict grid layout. A pretty common one is State and Zip. Following the grid's system, you'll most likely have these on two lines or have to do some special work to get them side by side and not share the same label (if you're a real stickler about each element having it's own label). And you'll run into others that are specific to what you're doing.

If you're going to be working on this project for awhile, honestly I'd just build your own CSS Layout (grid, flow or whatever works best for you). Or use an existing one purely as the base for your columns and that's it. You'll not use 1/2 of the CSS/grid foundation that comes prepackaged and make so many of your own custom modifications for special cases that it just wont matter in the long run. I also don't like the excess CSS classes that need to be applied to everything in most grid systems, either. Makes it difficult for mass changes later.

Lastly, you asked about tools. Working in pure CSS with a bunch of nice additional tools, I really like [TopStyle Pro](http://www.topstyle4.com/), Microsoft's VisualStudio text editor is by far one of the best out there, so there's nothing wrong with it either. I've not really worked in the child products like Web Developer Express and that other one, but it's not the same text editor. You can ignore those other panels they offer as they're complete rubbish. [Adobe's Dreamweaver](http://www.adobe.com/products/dreamweaver.html) is really nice as well.

Answer (score 0):

Joshua's answer is great.

ASP.net shouldn't be a variable any more than any other back end language. What does matter is that you use said language in a way that it doesn't automatically spit out HTML that you don't want *cough---sharepoint---cough*.

I've used the blueprint grid system on a large site which had extensive form needs. We used blueprint as our base philosophy and then wrote our own 'form grid' logic to accommodate our particular needs on top of it. That's likely the route you will be taking.

I'd read up on OOCSS (object oriented CSS) as that's also a necessity IMHO on larger dev teams that need to produce a lot of front end markup:

http://oocss.org/

Answer (score 0):

The 960 Grid System is an effort to streamline web development workflow by providing commonly used dimensions, based on a width of 960 pixels.

http://960.gs/

I've used this on many projects with simple and complex layouts. 960 GS works well and is easy to learn.

I choose this product for two reasons:

1. They have a huge existing client base that will testify success with 960.
2. All modern monitors support at least 1024 × 768 pixel resolution. 960 is divisible by 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15, 16, 20, 24, 30, 32, 40, 48, 60, 64, 80, 96, 120, 160, 192, 240, 320 and 480. This makes it a highly flexible base number to work with.

Although I must point out that your question is only loosely related to ASP. You really just want the ability to manage complex layouts using CSS

Answer (score 0):

Old Question, but good one. So here is my decision:

Currently the rise of responsive web design techniques, which facilitate the development of websites that can adapt to various resolutions for different mobile and desktop devices, is leading to the emergence of responsive frameworks. That is, they solved the common problem of making a responsive site.

Selection of framework varies depended on needs. Whether we have to choose simple framework or complete framework. The 1140 CSS Grid system is a bit old one and at present it is retired which is a very simple framework. For a complete framework, you may go for Bootstrap https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap or Foundation http://foundation.zurb.com/ or Pure http://purecss.io/ .

As an Asp.Net web designer, my preference is Bootstrap. Sleek, intuitive, and powerful front-end framework for faster and easier web development. Built at Twitter by @mdo and @fat, an ongoing developing complete framework.